# Problem in importing records from one table to another table

Tags: mysql

```
i m trying to import records from one table to another table.
```

i m having tables suppose A,B,C,D.
i m importing records from table A to table B.
Table B has two foreign keys which are primary keys in table C and D.
I m using query as below::

INSERT INTO B(userid,behaviorid,userNid,behaviorNid,timestamp)SELECT userid,behaviorid,userNid,behaviorNid,timestamp FROM A where userNid = ANY (select Nid from C);

but i m getting error as foreign key constraints fails.
How can i solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you add a bit description to what are you trying to do in the latter section `SELECT  
userid,behaviorid,userNid,behaviorNid,timestamp FROM A where userNid = ANY 
(select Nid from C); ` . Are you trying to join A and C table. And you got very low acceptant rate.

Comment: Please post the table definitions, What are the 2 foreign keys?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister id from table C and D are foreign keys in table B.

Comment: @experimentX i m having two schemas.i m trying to import records from Schema.A to Schema.B.i m having two more tables c,D.the id from both these tables are foreign keys in table B.so i m trying to compare id from table C with Nid in table A and id from tble C is foreign key in table A and if they match then only insert record from table A to table B.

Comment: well mail me your db sql file at santoshlinkha@hotmail.com

Comment: disable check using foreign_key_checks = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this should check `Nid` in `C` for every foreign key in C and append to B.

```
INSERT INTO B(userid,behaviorid,userNid,behaviorNid,timestamp) SELECT
 userid,behaviorid,userNid,behaviorNid,timestamp FROM A LEFT JOIN C on A.foreignkey = C.Nid;
```

Make sure you try it and comment, if not working